# Android selector state for selected items in android 2.3?

Tags: android, android-drawable, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to use a ListView inside the Navigation Drawer of my application. I'd like to let people select multiple items in this ListView (corresponding to some tags in my app), and show which one are selected to the user.

I'm using the following drawable on Android >=4.0, which is set as the background of every items in my listview.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And it works very well for that version. But on Android 2.3 (emulator), it doesn't show any feedback once selected.

I also tried other selector drawables which didn't work any better on my emulator, such as

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/solid_white" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/solid_white" android:state_activated="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_focused" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

Note that in my Java code, I use the following line to set the item selected when the user click on it:

```
this.mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Have you tried using state_selected instead of state_activated?

Comment: @Jonathan still the same if I replace state_activated by state_selected. Even I try both...

Answer (score 2):

So, thanks to a comment on a tutorial posted by Jonathan, I managed to find a workaround.

Since state_activated as only be added on Android API level 11, older device can't use it. But, they can use state_checked, so you just need to add a `layout-v11` folder which contains your uptodate layout (for me it was a `TextView`), and put in the `layout` folder, the layout for older version of android, which can be checked (for me it was a `CheckedTextView`).

Then, on your `list.onItemClickListener` you can can now check the API lvl, and         `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)`, then just check the CheckedTextView `viewClicked.setChecked(!viewClicked.isChecked());`

Comment: in my case CheckedLinearLayout, i think Google Android team should make a fix for this since this is not a solution for fragmentation or somehow minimizing it.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like your problem is that the state_activated parameter was not introduced until API level 11, aka Android 3.0.  Luckily there is hope for you; take a look at [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-list-indicators-on-honeycomb/) and see if it gets the job done.

Comment: Except, it doesn't really get the job done. It works for API>3.0 (like in my application), but doesn't in API<3.0. With this tutorial you can just avoid crashes on API<3.0 (and I didn't have any crash). But this is where the problem comes from.